# What is the TypeScript return type of a React stateless component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What would the return type be here?

```
const Foo
  : () => // ???
  = () => (
    <div>
      Foobar
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

`StatelessComponent` type mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44259550/1408451) has been deprecated because after introducing the Hooks API they are not always stateless.

A function component is of type `React.FunctionComponent` and it has an alias `React.FC` to keep things nice and short.

It has one required property, a function, which will return a `ReactElement` or `null`. It has a few optional properties, such as `propTypes`, `contextTypes`, `defaultProps` and `displayName`.

Here's an example:

```
const MyFunctionComponent: React.FC = (): ReactElement => {
  return <div>Hello, I am a function component</div>
}
```

And here are the types from @types/react 16.8.24:

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
interface ISomeCoolInterface {
   some: 'string';
   cool: 'string';
   props: 'string' 
}    

const SomeCoolComponent
    : React.FC<ISomeCoolInterface> 
    = ({ some, cool, props }): JSX.Element => {
        return <SomeCoolComponent>{some, cool, props}</SomeCoolComponent>      
    }
```

The important bit here being the return type `JSX.Element`

Comment: Another poster said it was ReactElement - is one preferred, or does it depend on the environment/TS version?

Comment: Yes `ReactElement` is the newer supported return type. I saw this change when moving to `eslint`

Comment: If I only specify `React.FC` in the above example, and exclude `ReactElement`, ESLint seems happy.

Answer (score 7):

The correct return type here is `ReactElement<P>`, but a better option would be to use `React.StatelessComponent<P>` like this

```
const Foo
  : React.StatelessComponent<{}>
  = () => (
    <div>
      Foobar
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: React.StatelessComponent has been deprecated meaning React.FC is the correct type for the component. The function will return a ReactElement.
`as of recent React versions, function components can no longer be considered 'stateless'. Please use FunctionComponent instead.`

Comment: This is outdated

Comment: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'StatelessComponent'.

Answer (score 7):

If using the `function` keyword, the best return type appears to be `JSX.Element | null`.

For now our team is using JSXNode as shorthand, since these are the only two types that can be returned directly as a JSX result:

`type JSXNode = JSX.Element | null;`

Edit: looks like eventually React.ReactNode is the intended return type for JSX but it's currently not possible.  ([Reference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/52080))

---

#### Background:

None of the answers here seem to address the most common modern case - that you have a function returning an element. What type should this return?

```
function MyComponent(): SomeTypeHere {
  return <>...</>;
}
```

The recommended way to hide the component is to [return null](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering), so it's not clear what clean return type that would be. Typing JSX.Element | null everywhere or even making a custom type like that seems it should be unnecessary given how universal this case is. ReactNode also doesn't work because undefined can't be returned as JSX.

Overall the best return type seems to be `JSX.Element | null`.  That is the return type of the `FC` type which is used if you're not using the `function` keyword:

```
const MyComponent: FC = () => { <>...</> }
```

Comment: function declaration !== function expression

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts

> Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(component, props, ...children).

```
function createElement<P extends DOMAttributes<T>, T extends Element>(
    type: string,
    props?: ClassAttributes<T> & P,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): DOMElement<P, T>;
```

So it's  `DOMElement<P, T>`

Comment: Seems to also be able to be a couple of other `*Element`s. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L129-L148

Comment: Yes, but in your case it's the one I mentioned, and I provided the link specifically for other functions you may write. Is there anything else that is not answered?

Comment: I don't think it is though, because `DOMElement<any, any>` throws an error, while `ReactElement<any>` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add `.SFC`, which stands for Stateless Functional Component.

```
const Foo
  : React.SFC<{}>
  = () => (
    <div>
      Foobar
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for traditional functions, maybe this ???

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";

export default function Home () : ReactElement<React.FC> {
    return (
        <>
            Hello world
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./App.css";

function App(): React.ReactElement {
  return <>hello</>;
}

export default App;
```

Use this in the react functional component.