# TypeScript React.FC<Props> confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I am learning TypeScript and some bits are confusing to me. One bit is below:

```js
interface Props {
  name: string;
}

const PrintName: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ fontWeight: props.priority ? "bold" : "normal" }}>
        {props.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

const PrintName2 = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ fontWeight: props.priority ? "bold" : "normal" }}>
        {props.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

For both functional components above, I see TypeScript generates the same JS code. The `PrintName2` component seems more streamlined to me as far as readability. I wonder what's the difference between the two definitions and if anyone is using second type of React component?

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133420/what-is-the-typescript-return-type-of-a-react-stateless-component It's more about properties you can find in React.FC.

Comment: https://www.harrymt.com/blog/2020/05/20/react-typescript-react-fc.html

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers. They are correct but I was looking for a more detailed version. I did some more research and found this on [React+TypeScript Cheatsheets](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#reacttypescript-cheatsheets) on GitHub.

**Function Components** 
These can be written as normal functions that take a props argument and return a JSX element.

```
type AppProps = { message: string }; /* could also use interface */

const App = ({ message }: AppProps) => <div>{message}</div>;
```

What about `React.FC`/`React.FunctionComponent`?
You can also write components with `React.FunctionComponent` (or the shorthand `React.FC`):

```
const App: React.FC<{ message: string }> = ({ message }) => (
  <div>{message}</div>
);
```

Some differences from the "normal function" version:

It provides typechecking and autocomplete for static properties like `displayName`, `propTypes`, and `defaultProps` - However, there are currently known issues using `defaultProps` with `React.FunctionComponent`. See this [issue](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#you-may-not-need-defaultprops) for details - scroll down to our `defaultProps` section for typing recommendations there.

It provides an implicit definition of children (see below) - however there are some issues with the implicit children type (e.g. DefinitelyTyped#33006), and it might be considered a better style to be explicit about components that consume children, anyway.

```
const Title: React.FunctionComponent<{ title: string }> = ({
  children,
  title
}) => <div title={title}>{children}</div>;
```

In the future, it may automatically mark props as readonly, though that's a moot point if the props object is destructured in the parameter list.

`React.FunctionComponent` is explicit about the return type, while the normal function version is implicit (or else needs additional annotation).

> In most cases, it makes very little difference which syntax is used,
> but the `React.FC` syntax is slightly more verbose without providing
> clear advantage, so precedence was given to the "normal function"
> syntax.

Comment: Hey Kuldeep, first of all thanks for the detailed answer. Maybe it is missing a link for "See this issue for details ". If I'm mistaken please disregard :)

Comment: Hey, the link for detailed explanation is the github link I mentioned in first paragraph. :) Thanks

Comment: Since React 18 an implicite `children` prop is removed. 
See: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210

Comment: How do you access the children from now on? Should I manually add a `children: ReactNode` property in my type definition?

Answer (score 87):

`React.FC` is not the preferable way to type a React component, here's a [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177).

I personally use this type:

```
const Component1 = ({ prop1, prop2 }): JSX.Element => { /*...*/ }
```

Short list of `React.FC` cons:

1. Provides an implicit definition of children, even if your component doesn't need to have children. That might cause an error.
2. Doesn't support generics.
3. Doesn't work correctly with `defaultProps`.

Comment: How to you type check prop1, prop2 etc?

Comment: @ArafatZahan You can write `{ prop1, prop2 }: { prop1: string, prop2: number }`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329592/typed-function-parameters-using-destructuring-and-rest-in-typescript

Comment: or `{ prop1, prop2 }: Props`

Comment: Use `React.VFC` if you do not use the 'children' prop

Comment: @KJSudarshan awesome note, should have more. upvotes or an answer

Comment: 1. Every react element has `children`, look at `React.createElement`. If you don't want them, don't render them. Or use `React.VFC`.
2. It is generic by design xD. But any way it is not a problem of `React.FC`, it is a problem of `.tsx` syntax. It fails if you want to make an lambda function with generic property.
3. `defaultProps` it is runtime part. Setting props from some external magic source is brrrr.. I will never understand this, because I can set defaults right in component.

Comment: React.FC supports generics, you can do React.FC<Props>

Comment: Addressing some of the comments on this answer: As of React 18 React.VFC is deprecated. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59882

Answer (score 40):

## Best solution:

The second approach + a return type

```
const PrintName2 = ({ prop1, prop2 }: Props): JSX.Element => { /** */}
```

This gives you complete control over the Props and is more explicit (there is no hidden magic).

[Link to GitHub PR to remove React.FC](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177)

[Kent C Dodds has some thoughts why this is here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-write-a-react-component-in-typescript)

## Sub-optimal solution:

The first version (React.FC) will add a few types for you - they come from the [React Typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5fe77324f2ad3714af2301f82925c93bf8e9b1b7/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L542-L548)

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  displayName?: string;
}
```

This approach is useful for a few reasons but an obvious one is if your component has children, then you don't need to manually add a `children` prop. It's not great because there are issues with default props and many components don't have children.

Comment: This is no longer the case, React.FC no longer includes the children prop! :D

Comment: @cdimitroulas would you recommend using React.FC now?

Comment: I have been using it everywhere, yes. I think it works great and gives good type safety to ensure you always return a valid value from all code paths. There is just one issue which is that for some reason it doesn't allow you to return a plain string from a component which should be valid

Comment: Explicitly adding : JSX.Element for a return type is not even required because TS is smart enough to figure it out by the return value of the component.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are using React and TypeScript, you should always use the first pattern, as it will ensure that your component is more strictly typed since it implies that the `PrintName` will be of type React Functional Component, and it takes in props of type `Props`.

```
const PrintName: React.FC<Props>
```

You may read the full interface definition for Functional Components on the React TypeScript typings [repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L517).

The second example you have provided does not provide any form of typings, except that it is a function that takes a set of parameters of type `Props`, and that it can return anything in general.

Therefore, writing

```
const PrintName2 = (props:Props)
```

is akin to

```
const PrintName2: JSX.Element = (props:Props)
```

as TypeScript is definitely unable to automatically infer that it is a Functional Component.

Comment: OK. but return type in second case should be inferred. hovering over it shows below: const PrintName2: (props: Props) => JSX.Element

Comment: While it will be inferred, sometimes inference is not fully correct but also if you add the type information first before you add the return value, you will get errors *until* you meet the return type specification.

Comment: It may infer it as a jsx element, but it does not automatically infer it as a functional component

Comment: Best answer, straight forward

Answer (score 5):

Don't use React.FC anymore. The reason why people used to use React.FC was because it added more types like children to your props.

in your code example you don't need children so just write it like this

```
const PrintName: (props: {name:string; priority: "bold" | "normal"}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ fontWeight: props.priority ? "bold" : "normal" }}>
        {props.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but the problem you will eventually have is that you will want to pass in children to your components and the preferred way of doing this is like this

```
interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {
   name: string
   priority: "bold" | "normal"
}

const PrintName: (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p style={{ fontWeight: props.priority ? "bold" : "normal" }}> 
        {props.children}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

extending with React.PropsWithChildren is the same as if you typed:

```
interface Props {
   name:string
   priority: "bold" | "normal"
   children?: ReactNode
}
```

React.PropsWithChildren can also be passed a generic but the default is unknown. If you want you can set children like this, but unless you are sure you only want a specific type I would just use the default.

```
React.PropsWithChildren<Button>
```

and pass in the type of children you want in your component.

You do not have to pass a return type of JSX.Element, because it's inferred.

Comment: So basically React.FC is old thing? I saw many frameworks using it and thought it gave some kind of significant advantage.