# TypeScript React: get rid of TS(2339) when extending a React.FC with a static property of type JSX.Element (uninitialized component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The typescript compiler in VSCode, currently at `TypeScript React 4.4.2` points to a `TS(2339)` error: `Property 'Col' does not exist on type 'FC<GridProps>'.`

I've tried adding this prop to `GridProps`:

```
export type GridProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  Col: JSX.Element;
};
```

But the error still shows. I think this is because the `Grid` component is not initialized. I've seen this convention of extending a main component with other uninitialized components such as `Grid.Col = Col` (see the screenshot), and it actually works when it is implemented:

```
<Grid.Col>
  {/* */}
</Grid.Col>
```

**How to remove the TS(2339) error in this case?**

NOTE: I've seen components like these before, the compiler doesn't throw and they don't event specify the Component prop in their prop types.

[image: screenshot that describes the error]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove `Col` in GridProps, Col is not a prop.

```
export type GridProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};
```

Second, to make TS happy, we need to specify the type of Grid component.

```
export type GridType = FC<GridProps> & {
  Col: FC<{}>;
};
```

And the implementation:

```
export const Grid: GridType = (({ className, children }) => {
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
}) as GridType;

Grid.Col = () => {
  return <p>hello</p>;
};
```

Demo here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-haze-w3o57?file=/src/App.tsx

Another approach is, using Function, not Arrow Function with `React.FC<>`.

```
export type GridProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};

export function Grid({ className, children }: GridProps) {
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
}

Grid.Col = () => {
  return <p>hello</p>;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-pike-1ir9i?file=/src/App.tsx

Another approach is, not to use `React.FC`. You can read more about this here: [TypeScript React.FC<Props> confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988667/typescript-react-fcprops-confusion)

```
export type GridProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};

export const Grid = ({ className, children }: GridProps) => {
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
};

Grid.Col = () => {
  return <p>hello</p>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Col />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Genius! If `Col is not a prop`, then what is it? Technically speaking. Also, what's the difference between the approach with an arrow function and a function?

Comment: you can think a function is an object (in JS function is a first-class object). so you can add a property to this object. but technically, `props` is a function argument. therefore `Col` is property of the object, not a property of the `props` object. By defined as an arrow function with `FC<GridProps>`, TypeScript will understand strictly than a normal function.

Comment: I just updated my anwser with an example of a functional component without `React.FC`