# How to correctly replace type any when returning children or map of children if array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a React function component that checks if children is an array. If it is not an array then it returns it. Otherwise it maps over the children and returns some JSX.

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const LineBreak: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }): any => {
  if (!Array.isArray(children)) return children
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, i, arr) => {
        if (i + 1 === arr.length) return child
        return <>{child}<br /></>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default LineBreak
```

What I would like to do is replace the `any` on line 7. I logically think that changing it to `React.ReactNode` would suffice, but that throws the type error:

> ```
> Type '({ children }: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'.
>   Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)
> ```

I could really use some pointers on how to properly read these error messages.

I also tried to bypass this error message by changing the return type to `string|React.ReactNode` and expected the same error because from my limited typescript knowledge React.ReactNode includes the type string.

Comment: The return type for a component is not a ReactNode it's a JSX.Element or JSX.Element[] see this SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/57363438/7645069

Comment: @MosheSommers tis produces a type error on line 8:
Type string is not assignable to type Element. I then expand it to be `JSX.Element | string | number | boolean | {}` to supress all of the errors from line 8 and it leads to the same error as the OP. It looks like I can resolve this by removing the React.FC type. Let me post an answer to myself.

Comment: Your right. You can have the return value be  JSX.Element  and wrap the children in the if with a fragment like so `<>{children}</>` so your always returning a single JSX.Element

Comment: Changing `React.FC` to `()=> JSX.Element` will also work...

Comment: @MosheSommers, if you want to provide an answer, I will give ^. My main question still outstanding that would be greatly appreciated: I could really use some pointers on how to properly read these error messages.

Comment: I put in an answer with my understanding of the error, not sure I'm right on that though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solutions from @amaster are good. Just adding my understanding of the error messages

I think this is what the error means

The error is saying that the expected return type for `FC<Props>` is `ReactElement<any, any>`

So
`Type '({ children }: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'.`
Means something with a return type of ReactNode doesn't match the expected return type of `FC<Props>`

And `Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.` Is saying you are trying to assign ReactNode as return type instead of the expected `ReactElement<any, any>`

Answer (score 30):

I was able to resolve this with two different methods.

1. Remove React.FC type from the function.

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const LineBreak = ({children}: Props): React.ReactNode => {
  if (!Array.isArray(children)) return children
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, i, arr) => {
        if (i + 1 === arr.length) return child
        return <>{child}<br /></>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default LineBreak
```

2. Wrap the single child return inside of a Fragment.

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const LineBreak: React.FC<Props> = ({children}): JSX.Element => {
  if (!Array.isArray(children)) return <>{children}</>
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, i, arr) => {
        if (i + 1 === arr.length) return child
        return <>{child}<br /></>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default LineBreak
```

From what I understand now, a React.FC can only be a return type of JSX.Element or equivalent. While children may be of type string, boolean, {} that does not conform to the JSX.Element type. So if I want to control the return type then I have to remove the React.FC, or if I want to use the React.FC, then I need to wrap the return of children inside of a fragment so that it correctly returns the various children types as a valid JSX.Element type.

Comment: How to call `<LineBreak />`

Comment: @Hary with either wrapping it around items you want to break:
`<LineBreak><>{"foo}</><>{"bar"}</></LineBreak>`
Or by passing in children:
`<LineBreak children={["foo","bar"]} />`

Answer (score 5):

The fix is to return `ReactElement` for `FC`. However you must also set `children` too.

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement
}

const LineBreak: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }): React.ReactElement => {
  if (!Array.isArray(children)) return children
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, i, arr) => {
        if (i + 1 === arr.length) return child
        return (
          <>
            {child}
            <br />
          </>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default LineBreak
```

Comment: This solution makes the most sense to me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use bad practice with FC interface, you will more problems with types, then whithout it, and I advice use PropsWithChildren, your case just use:

```
const View = ({children}: PropsWithChildren) => {...}
```

and not set return type for component React, so Typescript will define correct current type. And I advice you will use fragment(<>...</>) for your react element/component everywhere, good luck)

Answer (score 0):

Using `PropsWithChildren` worked for me as well.

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

const LineBreak: React.FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }): React.ReactElement | React.ReactNode  => {
  if (!Array.isArray(children)) return children
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, i, arr) => {
        if (i + 1 === arr.length) return child
        return <>{child}<br /></>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default LineBreak
```